# why [pg_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given]

Tags: php

I wanna pick up record and show but this error happen.

this error was not happen when I add ['] both sides of post and id in line 30.

anyway I don't no why $post['name'] and $post['content'] doesn't appear.

[table has a data by me on this program.]

please give me advice.

```
<?php
include'php.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>board</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <?php if(count($errors)): ?>
     <ul>
      <?php foreach($errors as $error): ?>
      <li>
      <?php echo htmlspecialchars($error, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>
      </li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
     </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
   <p>name</p>
   <input type="text" name="name">
   <p>comment</p>
   <textarea type="textarea" name="content"></textarea>
   <br>
   <input type="submit">
  </form>

  <?php 
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC";
   $sth = $dsn->prepare($sql);
   $result = $sth->execute();
  ?>

  <?php if ($result !== false && pg_num_rows($result)): ?>
   <ul>
    <?php while ($post = pg_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
    <li>
     <?php echo htmlspecialchars($post['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
     <?php echo htmlspecialchars($post['contents'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
   </ul>
  <?php endif; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

php.php

```
$dsn = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=board host=127.0.0.1 port=5432', 'postgres', 'Bossmanbig123');
```

Comment: Obviously `PDO` and `pg_` are __different apis__

Comment: er, you can't create a connection and query using PDO and then expect to use the results of it with pgsql. They're two different things. PDO manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php . pgsql manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pgsql.php. Choose one library and stick to it.

Comment: Also the fact it complains about a `bool` means `$result` is a boolean true or false. Most likely it's `false` which means your original PDO-based query failed. https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php shows you how to set up PDO to throw exceptions when errors occur. That way you might be able to get to the root of that particular problem. (Make sure PHP is also set up to log errors and warnings as well, so your PDO exceptions get written to a log file - see https://stackify.com/php-error-logs-guide/ for a setup guide to that).